# ISAPI Redirect a URL to another URL

Tags: isapi, isapi-rewrite, helicontech, isapi-redirect

I am new to Rewrite ISAPI and need help redirecting a URL from am existing to our standard IIS page.

Current page: https://store.md1.company.com/store/1/home

Redirect to https://store.md1.company.com

I currently use Helicon ISAPI 3 for all of my proxy rewrites and redirects, but I have tried a number of ways and I just can't get there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code Tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.md1.company\.com\/store/1/home$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://store.md1.company.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Please add your attempts for people to review/build upon.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.md1.company\.com\/store/1/home$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://store.md1.company.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]